# Consuming ASP.NET Web API from ASP.NET MVC and mobile devices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

After alot of in vain search on this topic, I need to ask the question here.

I am planning on creating an online multiplayer cards game. Initially, the game is only going to played via Android phones (as clients). But later, I would also like to make it accessible to iPhone users as well as make it web-browser based.

All these three types of clients (Android, iPhone and web browser) should be able to connect to the same server (where game engine is implemented) and therefore use the same logic and game-rules - their client-side appearance is whats going to be different.

I have programmed in ASP.NET and that is what I am planning to use here as the server-side infrastructure. Specifically, I have looked the ASP.NET Web API and it looks great: my three types of clients would *simply* need to get game data from the Web API as json and render it.

Here is my question:
Its clear to me how iPhone and Android will get and use that json-formatted game data from the Web API. But I am very unclear on how the website version (which I think is going to be ASP.NET MVC) would consume the Web API? Is it wise to simply make http requests to Web API from MVC - if yes, would it not make it slow?

Essentially, I want to write the game logic once, expose it through Web APi to many different kinds of clients that consume it. This architecture, that I have in mind, is beautifully depicted in diagram #3 [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/01/on-the-coexistence-of-asp-net-mvc-and-webapi.aspx) - cant post images here.

So *Others* on the diagram there, represent my iPhone and Android users.

Any pointers in other directions are also welcome. :)
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API controllers should be very thin, which you can achieve by extracting your business logic even further away, something like:

```
public class GameController : ApiController
{
    GameLogic _gameLogic; // inject through constructor

    public PlayCardResult PlayCard(Card card)
    {
        return _gameLogic.PlayCard(card);       
    }   
}
```

Then from your MVC front end, you can basically copy the controllers, performing the same methods on the GameLogic:

```
public class GameController : Controller
{
    GameLogic _gameLogic;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlayCard(Card card)
    {
        var model = _gameLogic.PlayCard(card);
        return View(model);
    }   
}
```

Alternatively, you can let the MVC controllers call the Web API, for example using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/):

```
public class GameController : Controller
{
    WebAPIClient _webAPIClient;

    [HttpPost]
    public void PlayCard(Card card)
    {
        var model = _webAPIClient.PlayCard(card);
        return View(model);         
    }   
}
```

Or you can let MVC be pretty dumb, and let the browser communicate with the WebAPI, for example [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. And yes good point about using something like GameLogic. So my GameLogic is going to be used by both MVC and Web API as clients and I only have to maintain GameLogic in one place?

Comment: @user yes, that was my intent. I don't know how you currently have it, but I would advise that road for reusability, as demonstrated above.

Comment: That is of course what I want as well - reuse the same logic. One last question. Can the Web API be hosted (publically) on its own - without any accompanying website - as the website will not use it anyway? So smart-phones can access it? You have cleared some stuff for me so your answer is accepted and thank you for your assitance.

Comment: @user yes, that's perfectly possible. You might want to create a separate Web API project for that, so no MVC artifacts are present.

Comment: Allright :) Now I can actually begin to write some code. Thank you once again CodeCaster.

Comment: In the first two blocks of code, are you using two routes? I do not understand exactly how will my application figure out which controller is should use. Could you as well explain `RestSharp` method a bit more, because I cannot understand exactly how it works.