# best way to consume Web API MVC by Website and Mobile device both

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-web-api

I am developing project in MVC with normal controller and Web API 2 controller.
I am using MVC 4 with Razor, Normal Controller for Website, WebAPI controller that will work as REST service for Iphone device or android device.i want to use normal MVC normal controller to take advantages of data annotations(required, regularexpression etc in Model) thats why i am using both API controller and Normal controller.
 I am writing my all DB related operation ( Fetch, insert, update, delete) in WebAPI. so that same method can be used by Website request and Mobile device request.
To access the method of WebAPI , i am creating the object like this.

just like this.

**WEBAPI Method**

```
public class AccountAPIController : ApiController
{
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post"), ActionName("GetSingle")]
    public UserProfile GetSingle(string email)
    {
       // return userpofile;


    }
}
```

**NORMAL MVC Controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Getsingle(string email)
    {
        AccountAPIController API = new AccountAPIController();
        var data= API.GetSingle(email);
        return View(data);
}
```

is this right way to consume WebAPI? please suggest the best way to consume web api both by website and Iphone or android device.

Comment: I think it is somewhat what you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741052/how-can-i-call-a-webapi-method-from-mvc-controller-action-method. Treat MVC as client of Web API so it is not directly depend on AccountAPIController so if later stage if you decide to separate web api layer then it works.

Comment: thanks @dotnetstep, what is best way to avoid hardcode webapi path and name of controller and name of method for each call

Comment: this [ANWSER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351453/consuming-asp-net-web-api-from-asp-net-mvc-and-mobile-devices?rq=1) confused me now. he is using object of webapi controller. please clarify me what is difference between these approach.

Comment: He did not. Actually He created WebAPIClient which is used to call Web api using rest. http://restsharp.org/ . You can have your own implementation of WebAPIClient.